# Классы и их наследование с#

Tags: c#, классы

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос в следующем:
Есть класс TableClassParent
вот выдержка из этого класса

```
/// <summary>
/// Название таблицы
/// </summary>
protected internal static string tableName;
/// <summary>
/// Запрос на создание таблицы
/// </summary>
protected internal string tableCreateQuery;
/// <summary>
/// Запрос на выборку из таблицы
/// </summary>
protected internal string tableSelectQuery;

/// <summary>
/// Конструктор с поиском из БД по произвольному параметру
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parametr">Параметр сортировки</param>
/// <param name="sql">Подключение к БД</param>
public TableClassParent(Parametr parametr, Sql_bs sql)
{
    GetSqlQuery();
    Parametres = new Parametres();
    Sql = sql;
    Exist_Table();
    string sql_query = $"SELECT * FROM `{tableName}` WHERE `{parametr.Name}` = '{parametr.Value}'";
    Processing_query(sql_query);
}

 /// <summary>
 /// Заполнение запросов
 /// </summary>
 protected internal virtual void GetSqlQuery()
 {
    tableName = "";
    tableCreateQuery = "";
    tableSelectQuery = "";
 }

/// <summary>
/// XML представление 1 строки таблицы
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">id Элемента</param>
/// <returns>xml node элемента</returns>
protected internal String GetAsXml(string id)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
    Sql_bs sql = new Sql_bs();
    var _tmp = new TableClassParent(new Parametr("id", id), sql); //Вот что я имел ввиду под словом рекурсия
    XmlNode nodeTmp = document.CreateElement(tableName);
    nodeTmp.InnerXml = _tmp.GetAsXml();
    return nodeTmp.InnerXml;
} 

public XmlDocument GetPageOfLogAsXML(XmlNode attribute, bool access)
{
    ....
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, Sql.connect);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string id = reader.GetString("id");
            XmlNode tmp = document.CreateElement(tableName);
            tmp.InnerXml = GetAsXml(id);  //интересует этот момент
            posts.AppendChild(tmp);
        }
        reader.Close();
    ....
}
```

Вот фрагмент одного из дочерних классов

```
/// <summary>
/// Конструктор с поиском из БД по произвольному параметру
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parametr">Параметр сортировки</param>
/// <param name="sql">Подключение к БД</param>
public Note(Parametr parametr, Sql_bs sql) : base(parametr, sql) { }

/// <summary>
/// Заполнение запросов
/// </summary>
protected internal override void GetSqlQuery()
{
    tableName = "note";
    tableCreateQuery = $"CREATE TABLE `{tableName}` (" +
             "`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
             "`user_id` INTEGER NULL COMMENT 'Id пользователя'," +
             "`text` MEDIUMTEXT NULL COMMENT 'Заметка'," +
             "PRIMARY KEY(`id`)" +
             ") COMMENT 'Заметки';";
    tableSelectQuery = $"select `{tableName}`.`id`" +
                $"FROM  `{tableName}`";
}
```

Теперь сам вопрос каким образом мне заставить инициализироваться переменные того же класса как и тот класс который запустил рекурсию.

Comment: `protected internal static string tableName;` - **static**??? И что значит здесь слово "рекурсия"?

Comment: странные куски кода никак между собой не связанные. Попробуй сделать **минимальный** пример того, что ты хочешь

Comment: Не по теме, но все же: не стоит хранить многострочные куски SQL-кода в C# файле. Создание таблицы обычно выполняют либо через какую-нибудь ORM с помощью разных билдеров запроса, либо можно хранить SQL в ресурсах. Я работал в одном большом энтерпрайз проекте - там именно так делали (весь SQL хранили в ресурсах).

Comment: static это был пережиток старого куска кода, спасибо что заметили поправлю

Answer (score 0):

Зря бучу поднимал извиняюсь.

Метод GetXml() сделал virtual и перегрузил его в дочернем ресурсе